# Add glyphicon to a webpage that was not created with bootstrap without compromising layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have an old website, and I would like to add a glyphicons to a page of this site.

I cannot install bootstrap (link bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css to this page) because it will change all styled elements on the page.

Is there a way to add only "glyphicons functionality"?

Comment: please stop tagging "bootstrap": it means something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your bootstrap to components, which you need, on

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

For example for **only glyphicon**, you can check only glyphicon checkbox and download.
Direct url for this setting is

**http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=428c81f3f639eb0564a5**

Scroll down and download it.

You download only two folders with css for glyphicon (bootstrap.min.css) and fonts files (in all only 170 Kb).

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use something called 'font-awsome' it has a huge library of icons and it only takes one line of code to include it into any project. - It works the same way as glyphicon being able to format with CSS etc.

I know this is not a answer to your question, but its a valid work around, and I prefer the font-awesome icons.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

View here how to include it on your website:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Have Fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can download glyphicons png on http://glyphicons.com/